# What is instance= in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
def addbook(request):
    form = AuthorForm()
    book_formset = BookFormset(instance=Author())
```

I know that `BookFormset` is an inline formset and that `Author` is an object.

Why is `Author` part of `(instance=)`; what does it mean and what does it do?

Answer (score 5):

As [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) states, the `instance` keyword argument is passed the model whose relations that the formset will edit.

> If you want to create a formset that allows you to edit books belonging to a particular author, you could do this:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
> >>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',))
> >>> author = Author.objects.get(name='Mike Royko')
> >>> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
> ```